# How to schedule a apex run after one other schedule is completed

Tags: developer-productivity

There are schedule A and Schedule B
I want to run Schedule B after Schedule a completed
Is there a way a way i can do it?

Comment: does schedule A invoke a batchable? or does it do all of its work in the schedulable execute()?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule another class by using system.schedule method but keep in mind you must implement the schedulable interface for the class which you want to schedule.

```
public class Batchclassparent implements Schedulable {

    public void execute(Schedulablecontext context){

        system.debug('inside parent');
        system.schedule('testjob', '0 0 14 * * ?', new Batchclasschild());
    }
} 

public class Batchclasschild implements Schedulable {

    public void execute(Schedulablecontext context){

        system.debug('inside child');
    }
}
```